# What is the complexity of the arithmetic operations in base $b$?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Fix a number $n$. We want an algorithm which takes a positive integer $x$, represented as a base $b$ string, and outputs the base $b$ representation of $nx$. Note that if $n$ is a power of $b$, there is a constant time algorithm: append the right number of zeros to the representation of $x$.

Is this the only case where there's such a simple algorithm? If $n$ is not a power of $b$, what is the complexity of this problem? I'm not asking for the running-time of any particular algorithm, I'm asking for theoretical bounds on how fast *any* algorithm can solve the problem.

I think it's reasonable to consider reading, erasing and writing digits as taking zero time, and focus on the number of single digit additions/multiplications that need to be perfomed.

More generally, are there known results on the complexity of adding and multiplying in base $b$ (or just base $2$) representations?

Comment: It seems like the complexity would be bounded linearly with the digit count in base $b$ of $nx$...  That bound would probably be computed as $\log_b(nx)=\log_bn+\log_bx$...

Comment: There is a vast literature on this kind of topic, Knuth's classic volume on "Seminumerical Algorithms" in his [Art of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) is a nice place to start for the basics.